# Clear the characters before the current cursor position in Zsh

Tags: zsh

In `bash` pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> clears the characters on the line before the current cursor position while in `zsh` this will clear the entire line. How do I clear the characters on the line before the current cursor position by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in `zsh`?

Comment: That's the default behaviour with both emacs and vim keybindings. What does `bindkey "\Cu"` report?

Comment: Answer is simple: run `bindkey \^U backward-kill-line `. @muru `"^U" backward-kill-line`

Comment: In MacOS, Ctrl+U also works in Zsh. In Windows it's simply Esc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bash and zsh work slightly different here. In zsh, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> clears the entire line instead.

Add these lines into your configuration **.zsh**:

```
bindkey -e
bindkey \^U backward-kill-line
```

You can use

```
$ bindkey
```

to list all of your keyboard shortcuts in zsh.

BTW: in bash you will print all bindkey with the following command:

```
bind -P
```

So no cheat sheets are necessary!

Comment: works like a charm!!

Answer (score 6):

In zsh, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> deletes the from the cursor back to the beginning of the current word.

Comment: That is an important answer that gives the WHY, thanks for this precision 

Comment: On my Mac Alt defaults to option for alternate characters.  Esc+k works though.